# In Magellan / Nightwatch, how do we assert that an element comes before another element?

Tags: nightwatch.js, magellan

For example, if the user has a gift card, we want to assert that gift card section comes first:

```
<section id="gift-card-section"> ... </section>
<section id="credit-card-section"> ... </section>
```

Otherwise, we want to assert that the credit card section comes first.  How can this be done in Magellan / Nightwatch?

My thinking is just to get the `N` in the `N-th child`... and assert that `N1` < `N2` or the other way around. How is this done in Magellan / Nightwatch?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great case for using XPATH.
Explicit, if you know that these should be the first and second section elements.

```
browser
.useXpath().assert.attributeContains('(//section)[1]', 'id', 'gift-card-section');
.useXpath().assert.attributeContains('(//section)[2]', 'id', 'credit-card-section');
```

or, if they need not be ordered, and they are at the same level in the DOM (if they are siblings) you could use attribute equals:

```
browser
.useXpath().assert.attributeEquals("//section[@id='credit-card-section']/following-sibling:://section[@id='gift-card-section']", "id", "credit-card-section");
```

This second option is a bit redundant, but there are plenty of other options if you are using XPATH in Nightwatch.